# Embedded FLV Plays in Fire Fox and Safari, but not IE

Tags: internet-explorer, flv

I have embedded a FLV file using the DW generated code, it does not work in IE, but it does play in Firefox & Safari. It even plays in IE off my desktop, just not live. Actual site http://business.queensu.ca/centres/qcbv/bsme/feature_ihg.php

Here is my code:

```
  <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="720" height="400" id="FLVPlayer">
      <param name="movie" value="FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf" />
      <param name="quality" value="high" />
      <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
      <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
      <param name="salign" value="lt" />
      <param name="FlashVars" value="&amp;MM_ComponentVersion=1&amp;skinName=Clear_Skin_1&amp;streamName=files/IHG_V4&amp;autoPlay=true&amp;autoRewind=false" />
      <param name="swfversion" value="8,0,0,0" />
      <!-- This param tag prompts users with Flash Player 6.0 r65 and higher to download the latest version of Flash Player. Delete it if you don’t want users to see the prompt. -->
      <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
      <!-- Next object tag is for non-IE browsers. So hide it from IE using IECC. -->
      <!--[if !IE]>-->
      <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="FLVPlayer_Progressive.swf" width="720" height="400">
        <!--<![endif]-->
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
        <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
        <param name="salign" value="lt" />
        <param name="FlashVars" value="&amp;MM_ComponentVersion=1&amp;skinName=Clear_Skin_1&amp;streamName=files/IHG_V4&amp;autoPlay=true&amp;autoRewind=false" />
        <param name="swfversion" value="8,0,0,0" />
        <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
        <!-- The browser displays the following alternative content for users with Flash Player 6.0 and older. -->
        <div>

        </div>
        <!--[if !IE]>-->
      </object>
      <!--<![endif]-->
    </object>
```

Comment: If that is the code for the video with the woman talking, then I checked it in IE and it works for me.

Comment: Thanks Chillie, but I don't know how you see it as I have tried different computers (home, work friends etc..) and no one is able to see it on IE6-9???

Comment: I have checked and it seems that my problem stems from the IE Compatibility mode, as my office has that permanently turned on, this is why I cannot see it here, nor none of my colleagues. Does any one know a code fix to have it display in IE Compatibility mode?

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a [IE Compatibility Mode Meta Tag](http://evolpin.wordpress.com/2011/02/25/ie9-compatibility-and-the-meta-tag/) to the code. This will tell IE that it should use IE8 mode or IE9 mode. which might fix your problem.

Code to use:

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" >
```

Comment: Thanks @Chillie I added in the meta code, and still am unable to view the video at my office, but feel better that with this tag most viewers will be able to.